# Python - Accessing Application Resources without Filepath Dependancy

Tags: python, file, directory, pygame, filepath

I am currently working on a [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org) application that uses spesific image resources. I am currently holding the application on Desktop (Windows). I have this code written:

```
image_resources = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/Pygame App/app_resources/image_resources/"
sound_resources = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/Pygame App/app_resources/sound_resources/"

class GetSource:
    def background(self,image):
        return pygame.image.load(image_resources + image).convert()
    def player(self,image):
        return pygame.image.load(image_resources + image).convert_alpha()
```

As you can see, I am organizing the application resources by putting the .py file and the "app_resources" folder in one directory, then under "app_resources" I create two directories, "image_resources" and "sound_resources". I have done research on it, but could not find any specific solutions, other the putting the .py and the resources in the same directory - which I do not want.

So, how can I work my way around this, and make anyone able to use the application, no matter where they put the application? Thanks!

Comment: hi! can you show us what that would look like? if someone puts the application/.py file wherever they want? if you try that right now, how does it not work?

Comment: For example, if they downloaded the app and put the folder in to "C:/users/Daniel/Downloaded Programs" the application would not work, since the code says it is located at "C:/users/User/Desktop". I want to access application resources without filepath dependancy :)

Comment: Have relative file path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have any experience with pygame, but one solution to bundling resources with a python package is the [pkg_resources](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html) module.

Then add relative path patterns matching your resources to your setup.py like so

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    ...
    packages=["myapp"],
    packages_data={
        "myapp": "relative/path/to/resources/*",
    },
    ...
)
```

Then you can access your data as so

```
import pkg_resources
data_stream = pkg_resources.resource_stream('myapp', 'relative/path/filename')
data = data_stream.read()
```

Besides a stream, you have `resource_string` and `resource_filename` methods available which are detailed in the link above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use directories relative to where your `.py` file is. Say that the directory structure looks like this

```
some_directory/
|-- myProgram.py
|-- image_resources/
|    +-- some_image.jpg
+-- sound_resources/
     +-- some_sound.wav
```

then `myProgram.py` can find it's own directory as such:

```
import os
programDir = print os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) # this is the path to some_directory in the user's system
```

and then you can use that path to go wherever you want relative to it.

```
image_resources_path = os.path.join(programDir, "image_resources")
sound_resources_path = os.path.join(programDir, "sound_resources")
```

Also, try not to use directories with spaces (you have one called `PyGame App`, since that can create issues with some systems, libraries, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the constructive answer. I will try it ASAP. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would say that using the pkg_resources library is a higher level solution and so: simpler, more robust and more flexible (usable in more contexts).